# groupBy in object JS

Tags: javascript, object, group-by

How can group data in the object, which would result in the 2nd version.

The data returned by the web api can be changed - it obviously binds to the key will not work.

Below is the format of what is now:

```
    var obj = {
    "0": {
        "@odata.etag": "W/\"1240107\"",
        "statecode_FormattedValue": "Open",
        "statecode": 0,
        "prioritycode_FormattedValue": "Normal",
        "prioritycode": 1,
        "activityid": "cb857c42-951e-e711-80d3-00155d0e443f",
        "_createdby_value_LogicalName": "systemuser",
        "_createdby_value_FormattedValue": "User1",
        "_createdby_value": "ea06239e-3918-e711-80d3-00155d0e443f"
    },
    "1": {
        "@odata.etag": "W/\"1240171\"",
        "statecode_FormattedValue": "Open",
        "statecode": 0,
        "prioritycode_FormattedValue": "Normal",
        "prioritycode": 1,
        "activityid": "374a8d72-4b39-e711-80d5-00155d0e443f",
        "_createdby_value_LogicalName": "systemuser",
        "_createdby_value_FormattedValue": "User1",
        "_createdby_value": "ea06239e-3918-e711-80d3-00155d0e443f"
    },
    "2": {
        "@odata.etag": "W/\"1224371\"",
        "statecode_FormattedValue": "Open",
        "statecode": 0,
        "prioritycode_FormattedValue": "Normal",
        "prioritycode": 1,
        "activityid": "f31ad69a-5339-e711-80d5-00155d0e443f",
        "_createdby_value_LogicalName": "systemuser",
        "_createdby_value_FormattedValue": "User1",
        "_createdby_value": "ea06239e-3918-e711-80d3-00155d0e443f"
    },
    "3": {
        "@odata.etag": "W/\"1224547\"",
        "statecode_FormattedValue": "Open",
        "statecode": 0,
        "prioritycode_FormattedValue": "Normal",
        "prioritycode": 1,
        "activityid": "6bee97d8-7939-e711-80d5-00155d0e443f",
        "_createdby_value_LogicalName": "systemuser",
        "_createdby_value_FormattedValue": "User1",
        "_createdby_value": "ea06239e-3918-e711-80d3-00155d0e443f"
    }
  }
```

And the format you need to get:

```
var obj1 = {
"0": {
    "@odata.etag": "W/\"1240107\"",
    "statecode": {
        "statecode_FormattedValue": "Open",
        "statecode": 0,
    },
    "prioritycode": {
        "prioritycode_FormattedValue": "Normal",
        "prioritycode": 1,
    },
    "activityid": "cb857c42-951e-e711-80d3-00155d0e443f",
    "_createdby_": {
        "_createdby_value_LogicalName": "systemuser",
        "_createdby_value_FormattedValue": "User1",
        "_createdby_value": "ea06239e-3918-e711-80d3-00155d0e443f"
    }
},
"1": {
    "@odata.etag": "W/\"1240171\"",
    "statecode": {
        "statecode_FormattedValue": "Open",
        "statecode": 0,
    },
    "prioritycode": {
        "prioritycode_FormattedValue": "Normal",
        "prioritycode": 1,
    },
    "activityid": "374a8d72-4b39-e711-80d5-00155d0e443f",
    "_createdby_": {
        "_createdby_value_LogicalName": "systemuser",
        "_createdby_value_FormattedValue": "User1",
        "_createdby_value": "ea06239e-3918-e711-80d3-00155d0e443f"
    }
},
"2": {
    "@odata.etag": "W/\"1224371\"",
    "statecode": {
        "statecode_FormattedValue": "Open",
        "statecode": 0,
    },
    "prioritycode": {
        "prioritycode_FormattedValue": "Normal",
        "prioritycode": 1,
    },
    "activityid": "f31ad69a-5339-e711-80d5-00155d0e443f",
    "_createdby_": {
        "_createdby_value_LogicalName": "systemuser",
        "_createdby_value_FormattedValue": "User1",
        "_createdby_value": "ea06239e-3918-e711-80d3-00155d0e443f"
    }
},
"3": {
    "@odata.etag": "W/\"1224547\"",
    "statecode": {
        "statecode_FormattedValue": "Open",
        "statecode": 0,
    },
    "prioritycode": {
        "prioritycode_FormattedValue": "Normal",
        "prioritycode": 1,
    },
    "activityid": "6bee97d8-7939-e711-80d5-00155d0e443f",
    "_createdby_": {
        "_createdby_value_LogicalName": "systemuser",
        "_createdby_value_FormattedValue": "User1",
        "_createdby_value": "ea06239e-3918-e711-80d3-00155d0e443f"
    }
}
```

}

Comment: is it a question or you are saying something.

Comment: It was a question.
How can you group the data in the object, which would result in the 2nd version

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the most efficient method to groupby on a javascript array of objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14446511/what-is-the-most-efficient-method-to-groupby-on-a-javascript-array-of-objects)

Comment: @MathieudeLorimier, not really, because just the objects gets new groups.

Comment: Little bit edited to make it more meaningful, look into it if its what you want

Comment: @NinaScholz Agree, my mistake

Answer (score 1):

You could define the groups for the keys and build new object with the groups.

```js
var object = { 0: { "@odata.etag": "W/\"1240107\"", statecode_FormattedValue: "Open", statecode: 0, prioritycode_FormattedValue: "Normal", prioritycode: 1, activityid: "cb857c42-951e-e711-80d3-00155d0e443f", _createdby_value_LogicalName: "systemuser", _createdby_value_FormattedValue: "User1", _createdby_value: "ea06239e-3918-e711-80d3-00155d0e443f" }, 1: { "@odata.etag": "W/\"1240171\"", statecode_FormattedValue: "Open", statecode: 0, prioritycode_FormattedValue: "Normal", prioritycode: 1, activityid: "374a8d72-4b39-e711-80d5-00155d0e443f", _createdby_value_LogicalName: "systemuser", _createdby_value_FormattedValue: "User1", _createdby_value: "ea06239e-3918-e711-80d3-00155d0e443f" }, 2: { "@odata.etag": "W/\"1224371\"", statecode_FormattedValue: "Open", statecode: 0, prioritycode_FormattedValue: "Normal", prioritycode: 1, activityid: "f31ad69a-5339-e711-80d5-00155d0e443f", _createdby_value_LogicalName: "systemuser", _createdby_value_FormattedValue: "User1", _createdby_value: "ea06239e-3918-e711-80d3-00155d0e443f" }, 3: { "@odata.etag": "W/\"1224547\"", statecode_FormattedValue: "Open", statecode: 0, prioritycode_FormattedValue: "Normal", prioritycode: 1, activityid: "6bee97d8-7939-e711-80d5-00155d0e443f", _createdby_value_LogicalName: "systemuser", _createdby_value_FormattedValue: "User1", _createdby_value: "ea06239e-3918-e711-80d3-00155d0e443f" } },
    groups = ['statecode', 'prioritycode', '_createdby_'];

Object.keys(object).forEach(function (k) {
    var temp = {};

    Object.keys(object[k]).forEach(function (l) {
        var group = groups.find(g => l.startsWith(g));
        if (group) {
            temp[group] = temp[group] || {};
            temp[group][l] = object[k][l];
            delete object[k][l];
        }
    });
    groups.forEach(g => object[k][g] = temp[g]);
});

console.log(object);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```